# How to trigger an event when target element is under another div

Tags: jquery, events, draggable, eventtrigger

Here is my initial HTML Structure

```
<div id="cover"></div>
```

At my div #cover apply a plugin for dragging it. I used this library : [kentor/jquery-draggable-background](https://github.com/kentor/jquery-draggable-background) and worked fine !

BUT When I would like add an overlay div like this :

```
<div id="cover">
  <div id="cover-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

the desired behavior of my div #cover is no longer triggered (I guess it comes from because my div#cover is "under" the div#cover-overlay.

Here my JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4byfurnq/ : You can test the normal behavior by removing the div #cover-overlay and dragging the div (in Y axis) in the results.

**My question** : How to trigger the desired behavior of my div#cover in this case ?

Thanks you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding

```js
$('#cover-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

At least this works in your fiddle. However, it will not work in IE10 and lower.

Comment: Thaks you It works like a charm ! I think there is an alternative to IE 10 and lower